# Symfony 2 / Doctrine does not load associated entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a problem with doctrine and a lazy loading one-to-many/many-to-one bidirectional binding.

Folowing Scenario (only necessary parts):

Two Tables:

```
Configuration:
type: entity
table: configuration
id:
    idconfiguration:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        comment: ''
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
    fkbasemodel:
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        unsigned: false
        comment: ''
manyToOne:
  basemodel:
    targetEntity: Basemodel
    inversedBy: configurations
    joinColumn:
      name: fkbasemodel
      referencedColumnName: idbasemodel
```

full code for configuration yaml:
    http://pastebin.com/v0G8TYqQ

and

```
Basemodel:
    type: entity
    table: basemodel
    id:
        idbasemodel:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            unsigned: false
            comment: ''
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    oneToMany:
        configurations:
            targetEntity: Configuration
            mappedBy: basemodel
```

full code for Basemodel yaml:
    http://pastebin.com/2aBRNF1g

Folowing DB Entries:

Basemodel-Table:

```
+-------------+
| idbasemodel |
+-------------+
|           1 |
|           2 |
+-------------+
```

Configuration-Table:

```
+-----------------+-------------+
| idconfiguration | fkbasemodel |
+-----------------+-------------+
|               1 |           1 |
|               2 |           1 |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

Configuration Class:
    http://pastebin.com/sWYgRpjr

Basemodel Class: 
    http://pastebin.com/yaiD8kCB

When i fetch an Entity of Configuration and invoke 'getBasemodel()'. It always returns null. Even if 'getFkbasemodel()' returns the right foreign key.

Why doesent resolve to the correct Basemodel entity? Its working the same way with other associations.

EDIT:

Added Pastbin links for full code

Comment: What does your Basemodel class look like?

Comment: Its too long to pase here: http://pastebin.com/yaiD8kCB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the full versions of the config you have multiple entries for oneToMany/manyToOne. Rather than specify that key multiple times you should just put all the relations of that type within one. Having duplicates like that makes yaml pick the last one as the only one (they are mappings (dictionaries) so you can only have one entry per key - also note that while the picking of the final entry is what happens this is not defined behavior).

You have:

```
oneToMany:
    configurations:
        targetEntity: Configuration
        mappedBy: basemodel
oneToMany:
    offers:
        targetEntity: Offer
        mappedBy: basemodel
```

Should be:

```
oneToMany:
    configurations:
        targetEntity: Configuration
        mappedBy: basemodel
    offers:
        targetEntity: Offer
        mappedBy: basemodel
```